# I want to use the UNIQUE_ID feature for future order amount prediction......Now how to feed the UNIQUE_ID to ml model? total rows is 1million

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

[image]**I want to use the UNIQUE_ID feature for future order amount prediction......Now how to feed the UNIQUE_ID to ml model? total rows  is 1million**

Comment: Any specific reason why would you like to use the unique_id?

Comment: Unique ID's are not normally included as features in ML models as they're not informative. Can you add some details about why you think they are necessary here?